# Javascript doesn't wait for function to finish before executing next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a very simple image change over thats suppose to fade out the current image, change src of image, and then fade back in the image. Here is the basic code ...

```
    $("#picViewer").fadeOut("slow");
    document.getElementById("picViewer").src = "myImage.jpg";
    $("#picViewer").fadeIn("slow");
```

Instead of ...

1. Fade out image
2. Change Src
3. Fade in new image

The Javascript doesn't wait for fadeout to finish and this is what you see ...

1. Change image src
2. FadeOut
3. FadeIn

Am I missing something? Also here is a bonus, ... will `JQuery` allow me to fade to a different color other than white or must I employ typical hackery to work around the situation?

Comment: Why *would* it wait? (The fadeIn/fadeOut functions setup "asynchronous" timers before they return.) -1 because [a small trip to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) explains how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional second parameter of `fadeOut` is a callback function which will be called after the element has finished fading out.

```
$("#picViewer").fadeOut("slow", function() {
   document.getElementById("picViewer").src = "myImage.jpg";
   $("#picViewer").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`.fadeOut` accepts a callback once done. You can place whatever you want to happen after fade out there.

The callback function also provides `this` as the element that just fade out. You can reuse using `this` instead of having to use the `id` of the element again to avoid hard-coding the `id` of the element in more than one place.

Also, you can chain jQuery function calls. Since `attr()` returns the object it modified (the `$(this)`), you can chain `.fadeIn()` to fade-in that same element.

```
$("#picViewer").fadeOut("slow", function() {
   $(this).attr('src','myImage.jpg').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

In effect, less code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#picViewer").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    document.getElementById("picViewer").src = "myImage.jpg";
    $("#picViewer").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations happen asynchronously, so what you want to do is use the callback of the animation method:

```
$("#picViewer").fadeOut('slow', function () {
   //change image src
   //fadeIn
   ...
```

If by fade color you mean CSS colors, then unless you are using CSS3 transitions, you must use jQuery UI (or some other plugin) to animate color changes.